# Restful issue with twitter public timeline

Tags: java, rest, twitter

I am currently studying RESTful and i come upon this example.

```
        URL twitter = new
                URL("https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/$userid.xml?count=1&include_rts=1callback=?");
        URLConnection tc = twitter.openConnection();
        in = new BufferedReader(new
                InputStreamReader(tc.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        // Write each line in the rectangle.
        // Note that we are likely to have more lines than
        //rectangle, but
        // it's OK
        int lineCount = 1;
        int yOffset = 20;

        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            lineCount++;
            System.out.println(line);
        }
```

The issue i am having is that the url I found in the book is outdated and they are not using it.

Is there any other url that I can use just to get the latest 20 tweets using the Twitter API?

PS:I am just looking for a new URL to use ,nothing else

Comment: This is not a programming issue. This is related exclusively to twitter.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter no longer offer RESTful access to the Public Timeline.

*All* of their requests **require** authentication.

See their API Docs https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1